# How to create a date in Javascript / JQuery from day, month and year?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

In c# it's enough to do:

```
new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

How should I do in JS?

Is the following code correct?

```
var birthYear = parseInt($("#BirthYear").valueOf());
var birthMonth = parseInt($("#BirthMonth").valueOf());
var birthDay = parseInt($("#BirthYear").valueOf());

var birthDate = new Date(birthYear, birthMonth + 1, birthDay);
```

Comment: `var DateTime = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);` ?

Comment: Yes, I couldnt find this question here.. if it's not a dup let's answer and I will accept!

Comment: -1, next time try to search in google -> create date in javascript-> profit !

Comment: There are already some answer there Revious, I'm sorry but I don't think I deserve any reputation for such a basic question that can be answered through google or whatever kind of thing. The only important thing is that you got it ;)

Comment: @mybirthname: look at EasyPush. Is it obvious? PS: I cannot write on Javascript page any explanation if it's not clear.. And it's very counterintuitive!

Comment: @briosheje: is it corect what EasyPush wrote?

Comment: Everyone wrote something correct down there, just choose the answer you prefere. The only important thing, again, is that you got it, regardless how precise the answer is, for such a basic task just check how simile is the javascript solution compared to the C# one ;). In any case yes, month January is 0, not that obvious indeed :). For more (VERY) precise infos, check the official MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date .. About the month, it is said that: http://prntscr.com/4w3qj9 <-- "from 0 to 11"

Comment: @briosheje: I can't understand those choices

Comment: Sometimes choices doesn't matter, or it really isn't worth understanding them. How do you know what happens when compiling? maybe every other compiler just takes your month value and decrease it by 1 to calculate the datetime.. So maybe javascript is right and all others are wrong? who knows ;) you're free to do a pretty basic function expecting the month value you want and return a date object with the correct month ;)

Comment: Re your edit: you need `birthMonth - 1` (assuming 1 <= birthMonth <= 12).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var whateverName = new Date(year, month, day);
```

Month is 0 indexed, so you need to put in 0 if you want January etc.

You can also enter negative months and dates. This will "count backwards" that many months or days.

This allows you to get the last date of a month by entering the month ahead of it and then 0 as the day.

Comment: Why this behavior for months, it's very different from java and c# :(

Answer (score 2):

```
var dateObject = new Date();

dateObject.getFullYear() + " " + dateObject.getMonth() + 1 + " " + dateObject.getDate();
```

Comment: I think is - 1, not +1

Comment: It's +1 because JavaScript goes from 0 - 11 in months.

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript Dates](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)

```
new Date()
new Date(milliseconds)
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```